# Extract full path link or value (when there's no full path link) in formula bar

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 workbooks. For simplicity's sake, I call it them destination and source workbook.

What I'm trying to do is simple, copy the formula that's in a particular cell on sheet1 in the source workbook to the destination workbook.

My problem here is that:

1. Source formula bar has either a formula or a static value.
2. If it's a formula, there'll be either 1 of these 2:

   2.1 Formula is a full path link i.e. \network_name\network_folder....[workbook_name.xlsx]SheetName'!$A$1 <----This is what I desire

   2.2 Formula is a full path link i.e. \network_name\network_folder....[workbook_name.xlsx]SheetName'!$A$1-A100-B200

My question is, how am I able to check if it's formula or not?

If it's formula, I'd only want the full path that reference to that cell, in this case `\\network_name\network_folder\....\[workbook_name.xlsx]SheetName'!$A$1`.
If it's a static value, then take it as it is.

Currently, I have (code below), but it's pulling the whole formula.

```
dst.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & x).Formula = srcShtName.Range("A" & z).Formula
```

Comment: To check for formula vs static value: `If Not Range("A" & x).HasFormula Then`

Comment: Thanks Alex! That solves whether it has a formula or not. But what about taking only the `\\network_name\network_folder\....\[workbook_name.xlsx]SheetName'!$A$1`  from  `\network_name\network_folder....[workbook_name.xlsx]SheetName'!$A$1-A100-B200`

Comment: Wouldn't something like this work without the worry about check if the cell contains a formula or static data? dst.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & x).Value = srcShtName.Range("A" & z).Value ;O